# Is this a form of fallacy of avoiding answering the question?

Tags: fallacies

Ok, I am dating a girl and I am feeling that she wants to borrow my moeny. Here is the conversation:

She did not ask me to give her money directly. But she said

> I: so, when do you think we can get married
>
> She: I want to work and earn enough money to build a house for my
>   parents because I am a good daughter.
>
> I: But you can do it later after a few years, you don't need to make
>   money now
>
> She: I need to build a house for my parents. About 50000USD.
>
> I: Can you do it later after a few years?
>
> She: Only 50000 USD, if I have that money, I can marry you & have kids
>   with you right away.
>
> I: Your saying sounds like you want me to give you money
>
> She: Have I asked you to give me money yet? Have I?
>
> I: But, you really want my money, don't you?
>
> She: you need to be matured, and think about your future wife
>
> I: I am asking you, Do you want my money?
>
> She: I have my dignity, I don't want to be offended

Ok, it seem that you did not answer my question "*you really want my money, don't you?*" & "*Do you want my money?*", but she somehow is trying to redirect the conversation to another topic.

I just want her to answer "*Yes*" or "*No*", but her answers are not natural. And anything that is not natural is abnormal.

**Is she giving some fallacies because of avoiding answering my questions**?

Comment: Her answers are perfectly natural, just not what you would expect if conversations were logical. They're not. What will you do if we answer "yes"? Go to your girlfriend and blame her of using a fallacy, forcing her to answer your question, which she already made clear is too direct?

Answer (score 3):

No.

The reason she is not giving you a fallacy is because the discussion is not one grounded in logical persuasion, thus the term "fallacy" is not a meaningful one.  The conversation is actually grounded in conversational etiquette, which abides by different rules.

Using that frame of reference, the conversation can be seen much more clearly.  She clearly has a desire for you to give her money, but etiquette prevents her from making it outright.  If she made the request outright, then the transaction would be "for $50000US, I'll marry you," which is a decidedly uncouth statement to make.

The purpose of such oblique wordings is very dependent on the tone of voice she chose to use (tone of voice does not extend to logical arguments very well).  If her tone was joking, she has simply stated that she needs to take care of her parents.  If her tone was serious, she has put the ball in your court.  You may elect to offer to give her money, spontaneously, or not.

If this situation is actually a serious conversation (as opposed to one of many joking tones it might have been), then I would recommend walking away from said relationship.  If she cannot accept "marry me first, and then we'll support your family" as an option, we have several derogatory terms for those who try to use the allure of marriage for financial gain.  Worse would be the derogatory terms for those who are sufficiently duplicitous to claim they have standards while doing so.

Fortunately, without knowing the tone of voice used, we can simply presume she was joking (which is more likely the reality).  In such a case, I would consider giving her a spontaneous donation of 50,000 in monopoly money.  Bonus points for then offering her a ring-pop ring.

Comment: She said "*Only 50000 USD, if I have that money, I can marry you & have kids with you right away*." with a very serious harsh tone_ Tom

Comment: In that case, I would very carefully consider the implications of "She: you need to be matured, and think about your future wife" and her surprising certainty that not only will she be your wife, but the implications of maturity that somehow arrive from giving somebody a remarkably large sum of money with no contract written around it.

Comment: I cannot probe your girlfriend's mind to know what she is thinking, so consider this mere hearsay, but I feel it is worth noting that I cannot distinguish her words from those of a scammer trying to steal your money.  Those happen to be exactly the kind of statements I would wish to make if I needed to answer pointed questions in a court of law later.  They could certainly be completely benign, or even a misinterpretation, but they don't look like she's on the up and up.

Comment: maybe she is not 100% scammer, she may have some feeling for me but at the same time she wants my money